# How to copy the values in a range from one sheet to and paste it another sheet on a predefied order using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the values in a specific range from one sheet to another. While pasting the values to the new sheet, there should be a predefined order in which the values are pasted.

[image]

---

[image]

I have created the program, but there comes an error in definition of For loop. Please note that in this example Num_Tacksta = 2, m = 9 (These two are variables).

```
Sub New_Try(m)

Dim n, i, j, x, k, a, rowinres, Num_Tacksta, Num_TackMul As Variant
Num_Tacksta = Sheets("ALLO").Range("E4").Value
Num_TackMul = (Sheets("ALLO").Range("E4").Value) * 2
x = Sheets("ALLO").Range("E4").Value


For rowinres = 2 To Num_Tacksta Step 1
    For i = 2 To Num_TackMul Step 2
        Sheets("Final").Range("A" & rowinres &, ",M" & rowinres).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Results").Range("A" & i)
        rowinres = rowinres + 1
    Next i

    For j = 3 To Num_TackMul Step 2
        Sheets("Dummy_Result").Range("A" & rowinres &, ",M" & rowinres).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Results").Range("A" & j)
        rowinres = rowinres + 1
    Next j

    For k = Num_TackMul + 1 To m Step 1
        Sheets("Dummy_Result").Range("A" & rowinres &, ",M" & rowinres).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Results").Range("A" & k)
        rowinres = rowinres + 1
    Next k

Next rowinres


End Sub
```

To my basic Knowledge in VBA, I think the problem is in this `Sheets("Dummy_Result").Range("A:M" & rowinres).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Results").Range("A" & j)` line. I would like to also ask if there is any simple method available.

I am new to programming and also to Stack Overflow. Helping me in this would be really helpful! 
I thank you guys in advance.

Comment: You are incrementing the outer for loop iterator `rowinres` also in the inner loops. Is that what you intend? Wouldn't `rowinres` become out of range too quickly?

Comment: Even if the `rowinres` loop loops more than once, you are overwriting your results as in each iteration of the outer loop the copy destinations in the inner loops (e.g. `Range("A" & i)`) will be re-used/overwritten.

Comment: I suggest you use the debugger to step through your code to see if it does what your intend it to do.

Comment: Hi @Paul, The control variable 'rowinres' can increment only till m, i.e 9, which is my requirement. My problem is to copy the entire range from source sheet "A & rowinres : M & rowinres". The code I tried is `Sheets("Results").Range("A" & rowinres & ", M" & rowinres).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Final").Range("A" & i) ` . This code copies only the A column of each row, but i wanted to copy the entire range from A:M. Please suggest me an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **colon** instead of **comma** in your copy range:

```
Sheets("Results").Range("A" & rowinres & ":M" & rowinres).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Final").Range("A" & i)
```

A comma is used in functions such as *SUM()* but a colon is used to specify a range.

Comment: This is exactly what i came here to update. Thank you very much for your support though!